# SQL Server TDSPacket consumes too much heap space

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, garbage-collection

Our web application keep on crashing with error message as "GC overhead limit exceeded" after 30 minutes from start time.

I generated heap dump at that moment and loaded into eclipse MAT. It mentioned that TDSPacket as the problem suspect. As this is the library we are using to connect to SQL server, I am unable to trouble shoot from here.

Any suggestion please. Here are the JAVA_OPTIONS used.

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=D:\Apps\Logs\tomcat\memory -Xms2g -Xmx2g -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Xloggc:gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=50 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M exit -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m
```

[image]