# Connection to MSSQL consumes too much memory

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

I use mssql-jdbc driver in version 6.4.0-jre8.
I execute a simple `SELECT *` query which may return millions of rows. In order to avoid OOM error I defined `responseBuffering=adaptive` and `fetchSize=10000`. I also ensured that the `ResultSet` is `type_fetch_only` and `concur_read_only`. Despite that I still get OOM error. The heap size soars to XMX limit immediately.

Below you can find memory dump analysis. I wonder why TDSPackets are not freed early enough?

[image]

I would appreciate any suggestions how to avoid OOM error here. Thanks!

Comment: I can see you are using debezium connector. Did you try https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc to see it you have the same problem?

Comment: @Brother Debezium uses mssql-jdbc connector under the hood. By the way, it is mentioned int the very first sentence :)

Comment: Sorry, it looks other people found the same issue (never answered though): https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1ba1f9d7-c34c-45f0-92a9-5f6adbab8020/microsoft-sql-server-driver-throws-out-of-memory-and-lots-of-tdspacket-classes-loaded?forum=sqldataaccess

Comment: Probably the same as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51403616/sql-server-tdspacket-consumes-too-much-heap-space ... if you manager to find out the reason, you can answer here as well.

Comment: For now, I think you will have to decrease through pagination the number of records retrieved each time <500 for example to help while facing the issue and not answered.

Comment: @Grzes - Have you tried adding `selectMethod=cursor` to your connection URL?

Comment: Have you tried a newer version of the mssql-jdbc driver?

Comment: Cursor helps, but I cannot use it due to some issues reported by DBA.
I also tried a newer version of driver, to no avail.

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DBZ-1065?focusedCommentId=13744584&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13744584


Avoid executing more than one statement on the same connection simultaneously. Executing another statement before processing the results of the previous statement may cause the unprocessed results to be buffered into the application memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the fact that I was executing multiple queries on the same connection simultaneously.

According to official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-adaptive-buffering?view=sql-server-2017#guidelines-for-using-adaptive-buffering

> Avoid executing more than one statement on the same connection simultaneously. Executing another statement before processing the results of the previous statement may cause the unprocessed results to be buffered into the application memory.

Comment: Hi, I have found that you have created Debezium ticket where this problem actually happend (https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DBZ-1065). How did you manage to fix this issue? Have you changed something in Debezium parameters? Or it was fixed by Debezium team?

Comment: @EugeneShatilo I answered this question in the jira comment. In a nuthsell, debezium avoids executing two parallel queries on the same connection. This is why there are two database connections kept: dataConnection, metadataConnection. It was fixed by Debezium team long time ago.